# Convert the date in the database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a database that you converted to WordPress
History in the old database (1472877023)
And the new (2014-05-16 18:49:52)
I did this code but it does not work

```
$Sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM no620_content3 ");
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($Sql)) {
    $dates = date("m-d-Y h:g:i ",$row['date_time']);
    $arid=$row['id'];
    $query = "UPDATE wp_posts SET ' post_date' = '$dates' WHERE ID = '$arid' ";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: is your field type set correctly in db? if u are passing a date time and your field is set as int type, it wont be updated.

Comment: The **[edit]** button is on the bottom left of your question, under the tags. Code in comments is very difficult to read.

Comment: mysql stores datetime as YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00 and not what you have there.

Comment: then `SET ' post_date'` that alone is failing; invalid identifier qualifiers (and a space). `mysql_error()` would have told you about that.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: have the answerers below seen my comments? they need explanations given and should not rely solely on my comments.

Comment: I have, @Fred-ii- , why do you ask?

Comment: @Don'tPanic to a certain extent; yes you have. Not about the quotes/space for the column ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to execute a bunch of queries in a loop for this. You can do it with one query.

```sql
UPDATE no620_content3 SET post_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time)
```

Comment: This is the result 2016

Comment: i want 2014-05-16 18:49:52

Comment: 1472877023 is not 2014-05-16 18:49:52, though.

Comment: I know this
This is an example
The output becomes in all 2016 data

Comment: The output depends on the input. If you have 2016 timestamps, you'll get 2016 datetime values.

Comment: thanks for the help     What do I do to get history this way 2016-05-16 18:49:52,

Answer (score 0):

Your DateTime format is wrong:

```
$dates = date("m-d-Y h:g:i ",$row['date_time']);
```

To get this 2014-05-16 18:49:52, you need to change that to:

```
$dates = date("Y-m-d H:i:s ",$row['date_time']);
```

Consider using the DateTime class too. And start using PDO, as the mysql_ commands are all deprecated and removed in all supported versions of PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php